# Extjs Having a displayfield with an image label

Tags: css, image, extjs, label, extjs5

I'm looking for a way to have a display field (a simple uneditable text with a text label on the side) but instead of a text label I want to add an image label. How can I do this without making my own class? I know I could make an hbox container with an image and an xtype: `label` but I'd prefer to find a way to take advantage of the `xtype: displayfield` and its label configurations like width, separator etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you prefer not making your own class, but maybe `labelCls` or `labelStyle` could be of help.
Granted using `labelCls` would involve creating the CSS class, but I think `labelStyle` would allow you to code the `background-image` directly.

Comment: I have tried labelStyle but for some reason I cannot get it to work. I've been looking for an example online but no one has a working one. Is it possible you can post a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I am unable at to get a fiddle, but try something like:  

fieldLabel: ' ',
labelSeparator:'' 
labelStyle: 'background-image:url(\'REPLACE THIS WITH URL TO YOUR IMAGE\');' 
If you need to specify size you can also set the width and height.
-
fieldLabel - cannot be a completely empty string, a blank space works;
labelSeparator - allows you to remove the ':' that would be place between label and field (if you need to)
labelStyle - works like inline css, you can easily set a string based on a property or whatever way you need.


Hope it helped

Comment: I tried that and although the image does appear in the label's place, it is repeatable and I cannot change its height (there is no labelHeight property). Also if I add no-repeat in the CSS line it breaks it and the image doesn't render for some reason. I'm pretty sure that if you try it you'll see it doesn't exactly work as you would have thought it would. That's why I asked for a working fiddle :p

Comment: Here you go, i think this is what you meant, if not i may have understood your idea wrong.
I tried several different styles to cover different needs, draw from them if you need :)
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bv2

Comment: Your fiddle works and it solves my problem. Something was wrong with my css syntax apparently even though I tried using configs etc. Anyway thanks.